# How to get the user entered value on the spot to assist proposal generation?

Tags: xtext, xtend

I am new to xtext/xtend, and would appreciate your help here. After reading a lot of online articles/documents/tutorials, I could not find a way on how to get the user entered value.

For example, let's say I have a simple grammar:

```
 Path: 'path' name=STRING
```

In the editor, the user entered:

```
 path c:/x
```

And I have a customized proposal provider with signature as:

```
 class DomainmodelProposalProvider extends AbstractDomainmodelProposalProvider {

   def override completePath_Name(EObject model,
                                         Assignment assignment,
                                         ContentAssistContext context,
                                         ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {
        ...
      }
  }
```

which will try to propose the list of valid paths based on the user's current input. For example, with `path c:/x` it would propose `c:\xyz` and `c:\x-ray` back when `ctrl-space` is pressed. To do that, I need get the `name` value to do the checking, but I don't know which APIs to call.

**EDIT:**
I was able to get the last suggestion from Christian working, i.e. by downcasting the Emodel object. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
 val pObj = model as Path
 val allowedList = DomainmodelStandaloneSetup.readAllowedPaths()

 var String tmp
 if (pObj.name == null) tmp = "" else tmp = pObj.name

 val target = tmp
 val proposedList = allowedList.filter[startsWith(target)] 

 for (item : proposedList) {
    val p = createCompletionProposal(item.toString(), context)
    acceptor.accept(p)
}
```

You can see I am struggling a little with the `val/var` constraints of `Xtend`. Had to use a val for the lamda, had to use a var to handle the case when `pObj.name` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generaral Answer to this question. but here are some hints that ususally work

- you can inspect ContentAssistContext for prefix
- you can inspect ContentAssistContext for the current ast
- you can inspect ContentAssistContext for the current and last complete node model

You could change your grammar to

```
Path: {Path}'path' name=STRING
```

and then downcast the `EObject model` parameter to `Path` and ask it for its name

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I am a little confused with the answer. Do you mean downcast `EObject model` is the 4th option, or it must be done for the prior three to work? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get the last suggestion working in my code with xtend. See the edit above. Thanks.

Comment: Xtend is much more powerful than you think: ```val target = if (pObj.name == null) "" else pObj.name``` or even ```val target = pObj.name ?: ""```